# react-native run-android crashed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

react-native run-android crashed with below error, things were working fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
npx react-native run-android
```

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1010 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compressDebugAssets FAILED
> 126 actionable tasks: 126 executed
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/AntDesign.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Entypo.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/EvilIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Feather.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Fontisto.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Foundation.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Ionicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Octicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Zocial.ttf' collided

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/AntDesign.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Entypo.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/EvilIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Feather.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Fontisto.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Foundation.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Ionicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Octicons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' collided
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> > Entry name 'assets/fonts/Zocial.ttf' collided

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 15s

```
at makeError (E:\x\uipoc\day2\x\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\x\uipoc\day2\x\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\x\uipoc\day2\x\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\x\uipoc\day2\x\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: im assuming your trying to add fonts? how about try deleting nodemodules and npm install and cd ios and pod install

Comment: 1) at this i am trying to just bring the app up, i am using android
2) i have already cleaned node-modules, ,gradle , ran npm install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Troubleshooting**

The icons show up as a crossed out box on Android

1. Make sure you've copied the font to
   `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`.
2. Delete the build folder with `rm -rf android/app/build`.
3. Recompile the project.

As mentioned in [Troubleshooting section](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#troubleshooting)

Comment: which fonts to copy? and why should I do it? `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` already has those fonts, deleting the build folder doesn't help

Comment: you just need to read the documentation here it is
Copy the contents in the Fonts folder to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts (note lowercase fonts folder).
available here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually

Comment: I have those fonts already there, the issue is not about missing fonts but about duplicating issue: `android\app\build\intermediates\ReactNativeVectorIcons\fonts\AntDesign.ttf: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources`

Comment: it seems I need to delete them - https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1416#issuecomment-1042519618

Comment: yes you need to remove them if you added them manually as well